# DOM : How to detect a new child elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to detect the insertion of a new `div` element *only as a direct child* of the parent `div`.

Example:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
    <div id="newChild">I want this element to be detected</div>
</div>
```

The `DOMNodeInserted()` event is not a solution for me because it is triggered on every element insertion, not just children.

Like:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
        <span>I don't want this new element to be detected</span>
    </div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
    <div id="child3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't, think if a better solution like emitting an event before you inject into the DOM

Comment: i dont have the real js code of the page so i dont know witch events are used. only injecting my code in it to detect something

Comment: **DISCLAIMER:** DOMNodeInserted is deprecated.

Comment: Replaced by MutationObservers - For everyone late to the party and wondering what the shiny new thing is:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume your event handler looks like this:

```
function(evt) {
    // whatever
}
```

Inside the handler, `evt.relatedNode` is the element into which the insertion is being performed. You can switch on it and decide to ignore or process the event.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/KEjke/1)**.

Comment: @NidhalRouissi - Just so you know, this doesn't seem to work for me in IE8.

Comment: its ok , this is for a Google Chrome extension

Answer (score 15):

Use `DOMNodeInserted` on the parent and check the `event.target.parentNode` of the added element. If its `id` is `parent`, then the element is a direct descendant.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/f2w7V/

```
document.getElementById( 'parent' ).addEventListener( 'DOMNodeInserted', function ( event ) {

    if( event.target.parentNode.id == 'parent' ) {
        //direct descendant        
    };

}, false );
```

Comment: @NidhalRouissi The demo link didn't throw one `alert()`?

Comment: DOMNodeInserted isn't supported by IE (8 and below?) and is deprecated: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use DOMNodeInserted, but add a check / if-statement in the event handler so the real logic only runs when you want it to?

Comment: DOMNodeInserted isn't supported by IE (8 and below?) and is deprecated: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted