# JS/JQuery: Detect when child element is added to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have parent div where child elements are added dynamically and i need to detect when child is added. I heard about mutation observer which is new version of DOMSubTreeModified event, but are there better alternatives?

for example

```
$('div').//event = () => {
  //do stuff
}
```

Thanks You!

Comment: output.innerHTML += `<div class='${hisclass}'><p class="he">` + encodedMessage + '</p></div>'

Answer (score 3):

Use DOMNodeInserted on the parent and check the event.target.parentNode of the added element. If its id is parent, then the element is a direct descendant.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/f2w7V/)

```
document.getElementById( 'parent' ).addEventListener( 'DOMNodeInserted', function ( event ) {
   if( event.target.parentNode.id === 'parent' ) {
       //direct descendant        
   };
}, false );
```

Credit goes to [ThinkingStiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866885/dom-how-to-detect-a-new-child-elements/8866924#8866924) who already answered that question